# Google Sheets API "update" method Http Error 400

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to make a python script that reads and writes to a google spreadsheet. I've basically copied the python quickstart script at https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python and modified it using the reference at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/.

Everything works fine with the "get" method shown in the quickstart script. I can read the sheet with no errors. To use "update" instead of "get" (write to the sheet instead of read it), I removed the `.readonly` portion of the scope url. I also replaced the `get()` method with `update()` and included `body` as an argument in the `update()` method with a json object containing the values encoded with `json.dumps`. This was all according to the second reference above.

I get an HttpError 400 every time for "invalid data".

Code:

```
import httplib2
import os
import json

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

    Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
    students in a sample spreadsheet:
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                    'version=v4')
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                              discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

    spreadsheetId = '1Wbo5ilhw68IMUTSvnj_2yyRmWJ87NP-lHdJdaPBmTGA'
    rangeName = 'Class Data!A2:E'
    body = json.dumps({'values': [[0,0,0,0,0]]})
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName, body=body).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Console errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Dropbox/python/jobs/test.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Dropbox/python/jobs/test.py", line 69, in main
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName, body=body).execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 832, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1Wbo5ilhw68IMUTSvnj_2yyRmWJ87NP-lHdJdaPBmTGA/values/Class%20Data%21A2%3AE?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'data' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.ValueRange), "{"values": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}"">
```

Comment: can you provide the code you attempted in your question rather than links?

Comment: the .json file you are using might not be the correct one please provide the console error trace, it should point us towards the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that the `body` arg included in `update()`, although shown in the documentation as json, actually needs to be a regular python dictionary. I was sending a body of text in json, and what the google api client was looking for was an actual python dict object I guess.

Comment: This solved my problem, and is the correct answer to the OP. Google's documentation is lacking, and I also thought it wanted JSON in a string.

Answer (score 7):

I also started with the API example. Above information about enabling both APIs, for Drive and Sheets, helped me solving the access error.

Then I found that the .get(...).execute() returns an object, which is the type that is needed as input in the .update().execute(), it looks like:

```
{u'range': u'Sheet1!A1:B2', u'values': [[u'cella1', u'cellb1'],
[u'cella2', u'cellb2']], u'majorDimension': u'ROWS'}
```

After having made a fit between ranges, and also adding the argument *valueInputOption='RAW'* to the .update(), I successfully wrote to the Google sheet with this code snippet:

```
myBody = {u'range': u'Sheet1!A1:B2', u'values': [[u'Zellea1', u'Zelleb1'], [u'Zellea2', u'Zelleb2']], u'majorDimension': u'ROWS'}
rangeOutput = 'Sheet1!A1:B2'
res = spreadsheet.values().update( spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeOutput, valueInputOption='RAW', body=myBody ).execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

I setup myself to have a google dev account and encountered several setbacks, but I was able to manage.

I'm pretty sure the 401 is due to the incorrect JSON file provided to authenticate (specially if you have several projects and have downloaded several JSON files)
[image]

I also encountered a 403 indicating the API for my google drive was not enabled:

[image]

make sure that you have both api's enabled (for the drive and the spreadhseets)
[image]

Most of the time, when executing my code, the console returned a pretty clear Error and pointed towards the right direction:

> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
>   googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/DocumentID/values/Class%20Data%21A2%3AE?alt=json
>   returned "Google Sheets API has not been used in project
>   pytestapp before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=pytestapp
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.">
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem appear, but the origin of the problem was different. I figured out someone had deleted a column. Therefore I was trying to parse data in a column out of range.

In case someone has the same issue, I solved it by first getting column names + numbers in a dictionary and parsing data according to column name.

```
    headers = wks.get_row(2, include_tailing_empty=False)
    headers_dic={x:i for i, x in enumerate(headers)}
```

and then

```
    wks.update_col(headers_dic['Column Name']+1, data_as_list, row_offset=2)
```

the offset=2 is because of the type of header in the sheet and the +1 in the column is because python and sheets start their index on 0 and 1 respectively.