# Mailchimp Google sheet issue with the api key

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api

All the variables are returning correct values but the the urlfetch response returns 403 or 401 (access denied).

[image]

First log output:

```
 var payload = {
    "apikey": API_KEY,
    "filters": {
        "sendtime_start": REPORT_START_DATE,
        "sendtime_end": REPORT_END_DATE
    }
};
Logger.log(payload );
```

Second log output:

```
var params = {
    "method": "POST", //what MC specifies
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": payload,
    "limit": 100
};
Logger.log(params);
```

Third log output:

```
var apiCall = function(endpoint) {

    //issue with syntax here?

    var apiResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(automationsList, params);
    var json = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
    Logger.log(apiResponse);
    return json;
};
```

Automation API Call that is not working:

```
var automations = apiCall(automationsList);
var automationsData = automations.data;

for (var i = 0; i < automationsData.length; i++) {


    // are these response parameters? are these specific values getting pulled from MC - these are the type of values i want?
    var a = automationsData[i];
    var aid = a.id; // identifies unique campaign *** does this have anything to do with the call function above - it used to be as cid b/c this was for campaigns before??
    var emails_sent = a.emails_sent;
    var recipients = a.recipients;
    var report_summary = a.report_summary;
    var settings = a.settings;

    if (send_time) {

        var r = apiCall(reports, cid); // why does this have cid? but the other one didn't??
        var emails_sent = r.emails_sent;
        var opens = r.opens;
        var unique_opens = r.unique_opens;
        var clicks = r.clicks;
        var unique_clicks = r.unique_clicks;
        var open_rate = (unique_opens / emails_sent).toFixed(4);
        var click_rate = (unique_clicks / emails_sent).toFixed(4);

    }
```

The for loop is not even gets executed because I get following error for automationsData:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "data" from undefined. (line 82, file "Code")

The apiResponse there is somehow not working, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using v3.0 for the Mailchimp api whereas I needed to use 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you set up your project in the Developers Console. Try to follow again the process [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) for you to verify if you already do it in the correct way.

You can also check the solution here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369157/google-sheets-api-update-method-http-error-400), he/she explained it here, why he/she get the same 401 and 403 error that you get.