# Google Sheets API returning HTTP error 400

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to delete a row in a spreadsheet using the Google Sheets API. When running the code, I am getting a 400 error. Here is the full code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # The ID and range of a spreadsheet.
    SPREADSHEET_ID = '1GrO8NHRKZzTVMRnG9FskjzhWLKJySWQxT2VSXcuRixw'
    RANGE_NAME = "B:F"
    batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
        "requests": [
            {
            "deleteDimension": {
                "range": {
                "sheetId": SPREADSHEET_ID,
                "dimension": "ROWS",
                "startIndex": 26,
                "endIndex": 26
                }
            }
            }
        ],
        }
    request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
    response = request.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/owcsc/Documents/GitHub/aotw/stackoverflow.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "f:/owcsc/Documents/GitHub/aotw/stackoverflow.py", line 54, in main
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1GrO8NHRKZzTVMRnG9FskjzhWLKJySWQxT2VSXcuRixw:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[0].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "1GrO8NHRKZzTVMRnG9FskjzhWLKJySWQxT2VSXcuRixw"". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'requests[0].delete_dimension.range.sheet_id\' (TYPE_INT32), "1GrO8NHRKZzTVMRnG9FskjzhWLKJySWQxT2VSXcuRixw"'}]}]">
```

I'm sure this is probably a simple fix but I couldn't figure out any of the answers I found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets API "update" method Http Error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369157/google-sheets-api-update-method-http-error-400)

Comment: @Rhys I saw that post, and it seems like the problem might be that a dictionary is needed, and not json. As far as I can tell mine is not in json format, but I don't know much about that so I may be wrong. It was mostly copied from the API docs so if the docs are wrong that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your error message is due to `"sheetId": SPREADSHEET_ID,`. In your script, `SPREADSHEET_ID` is declared as `SPREADSHEET_ID = '1GrO8NHRKZzTVMRnG9FskjzhWLKJySWQxT2VSXcuRixw'`. I think that this is the Spreadsheet ID. But in the case of `sheetId`, this is the sheet ID in the Google Spreadsheet. You can see about Sheet ID at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id). It's as follows. For example, if you want to use the 1st tab in the default Google Spreadsheet, the sheet ID is `0`.

  ```
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/edit#gid=sheetId
  ```
- And, in your script, `"startIndex": 26,`, `"endIndex": 26`, and `"dimension": "ROWS",` are used. In this case, no rows are deleted. Because `startIndex` and `endIndex` are the same. For example, when you want to delete the row 26, please modify `"startIndex": 26,` to `"startIndex": 25,`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
        "deleteDimension": {
            "range": {
            "sheetId": 0, # <--- 0 or please set the specific sheet ID you want to use.
            "dimension": "ROWS",
            "startIndex": 25,  # <--- In this case, row 26 is deleted.
            "endIndex": 26
            }
        }
        }
    ],
    }
```

#### References:

- [Sheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)